# Transition legacy software from Windows XP on Windows 10

Tags: windows, sql, vb

I have a 'general' question regarding transitioning legacy software from Windows XP to Windows 10. I will provide all relevant info and the reason for doing so. Firstly, the legacy software was coded by a software engineer in 2006 on Windows XP. The software was coded in Visual Studio 2005, and SQL Server Manager Express 2005. It also uses crystal reports. This software writes very simple tables and integrates with the Bloomberg API. It's used for maintaining portfolio management data (we are an investment management firm). It's relatively simple code, to my understanding. Personally, I have no computer science experience but would say intuitively understand quite a bit and have no been given the task to transition from windows XP to windows 10. The reason for the transition in operating systems is: 1. Windows XP 32 bit only allows up to ~3.5GB of ram, Bloomberg now requires 4GB minimum 2. Bloomberg doesn't support windows XP any longer

In order to complete the transition, my ideas are as follows (in order of difficulty of execution/time required). For what it's worth this is all being done on a test computer, of course.

Start with Windows 10, use the Norton Ghost image that we have - not sure this will even work?

Start with Windows XP, use the Norton Ghost image, upgrade to windows 10
Start with a fresh Windows 10 install, try to recreate the directories, ODBC export/import, etc.

Hire someone else to do it (any ideas what a cheap option for this is?)

The problem I foresee in all of this is the connections between all of the software. I think the code will work (SQL/VB) but I think there will be issues in linking the excel macros with the SQL tables, the VB with Bloomberg (this is probably in the code and just needs proper directories), etc. But I hope if I import the ODBC it will work?

Basically I'm grasping at straws here but hope that just flashing an image will place all the directories in the right place and I'll just have to deal with legacy code which I can probably contract out.

Am I missing some simpler way to do this? I have instructions written by the person who wrote the code, which if necessary I can paste here (if maybe it makes it easier to understand what's going on, I'm not sure I explained it all that well).

Thank you for any help

Comment: Do you have the install for the Program?

Comment: To keep the answer short: "Hire someone else to do it" is exactly what you should do!

Comment: Set up a test Windows 10 machine (physical or virtual), install the software (whatever that involves), test the software, work with the developer of the software (or hire one if the original developer isn't available) and work out the kinks. You're worried about problems that you don't even know exist yet. Set up a test machine and then determine what does and doesn't work and proceed from there. The only way to know what will and won't work is to do it. Don't create a list of problems for yourself before those problems even manifest themselves.

Comment: If that is written in Visual Basic it was mismanaged. VB was already known to not be maintained in 2000 - years earlier. And your company did not consider maintenance to be a task - so now things are REALLY crappy.

Answer (score 0):

Norton Ghost is no longer supported - Windows 7 was the last version to have NG version that worked. (Windows 8+ there is versions of NG that works)

You can install legacy apps on Windows 10. Most times the VB Com objects need to be installed on top of the normal program. VB Runtime
[VB Runtime Install](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=24417)
Worst case, you have to do some regsvr32 install of the remaining DLL/OCX
[How to use regsvr32](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/249873)
Even though that is from XP it works the same on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be run as a remote/published application?

Server 2008 x86 is supported to 2020 and will run even 16 bit apps as a published application....